# How do I load an image at run time?

Tags: c#, xna

Hello guys I've tried to call an image at run time in XNA but it gives me an error `"file not found"` I've given the full path but it keeps returning a error. All I want is load a single image at some point the image does not exist when the game is executed (hard to explain). So I wanted to load this image generated by the game process is it possible?

```
if (File.Exists(FILE))//Checks if the file exist

   ImageTexture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"C:\FullPath");
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions

Answer (score 2):

A: What is `"C:\FullPath"`? It's nothing. I very much doubt you have a file there.

B: XNA requires you load a local file if you're going to use Content.Load - it must be in the `GamePath/Content` folder. EG: `GamePath/Content/MySprite.xnb`

C: If you want to load a random image, you must use `Texture2D.FromStream`, like so:

```
System.IO.FileStream mystream = new System.IO.FileStream("C:/MyFile.png", System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
Image = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, mystream);
mystream.Dispose();
```

Comment: Good Answer although you could leave A out.